# Azure Powershell Workflow - Input Parameters Not Found

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell

### Background

I have a workflow defined using a straightforward template from within Azure.

```
workflow Use-SqlCommandSample
{
param(
    [parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [string] $SqlServer,

    [parameter(Mandatory=$False)]
    [int] $SqlServerPort = 1433,

    [parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [string] $Database,

    [parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [string] $Table,

    [parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [PSCredential] $SqlCredential
)

# Get the username and password from the SQL Credential
$SqlUsername = $SqlCredential.UserName
$SqlPass = $SqlCredential.GetNetworkCredential().Password

inlinescript {
    # Define the connection to the SQL Database
    $Conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Server=tcp:$using:SqlServer,$using:SqlServerPort;Database=$using:Database;User ID=$using:SqlUsername;Password=$using:SqlPass;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;")

    # Open the SQL connection
    $Conn.Open()

    # Define the SQL command to run. In this case we are getting the number of rows in the table
    $Cmd=new-object system.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) from dbo.$using:Table", $Conn)
    $Cmd.CommandTimeout=120

    # Execute the SQL command
    $Ds=New-Object system.Data.DataSet
    $Da=New-Object system.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter($Cmd)
    [void]$Da.fill($Ds)

    # Output the count
    $Ds.Tables.Column1

    # Close the SQL connection
    $Conn.Close()
}
}
```

### Issue

When I go to either test the workflow or run it, I'm not prompting for any input parameters.
[image: No input parameters]

Comment: try saving the runbook and go to test again, also try saving the runbook and accessing the test using another browser and\or another PC\incognito mode.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try putting your parameters at the top like this. Works for my runbooks.

```
param(
    [parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [string] $SqlServer,

    [parameter(Mandatory=$False)]
    [int] $SqlServerPort = 1433,

    [parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [string] $Database,

    [parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [string] $Table,

    [parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [PSCredential] $SqlCredential
)

workflow Use-SqlCommandSample
{
    # Get the username and password from the SQL Credential
    $SqlUsername = $SqlCredential.UserName
    $SqlPass = $SqlCredential.GetNetworkCredential().Password
    ...
}
```

Comment: It's just amazing that all Microsoft documentation examples have parameters defined within the workflow section! It doesn't work, but having them outside of the workflow section works just fine...

Comment: ah, now I understand more of it. If you create a runbook of type "powershell" it won't run as a workflow. That seems like the reason why parameters won't work inside the workflow section. If you create a runbook of type Powershell Workflow, you can have the parameters inside the workflow section and it works (at least for me)